# format swagger document text style solution

Tags: swagger

I have a swagger fragment like this

```
responses: { '200': { description: 'Agent data', schema: { type: object, properties: { agentRecord: { type: object, properties: { username: { type: string }, vpnname: { type: string }, google_id: { type: string } } }, googleRecord: { type: object }, agentACLs: { type: object } } } }, default: { description: 'Unexpected error', schema: { $ref: '#/definitions/Error' } } }
```

but I want it to be like

```
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Successful response",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Success"
        }
      },
```

How to convert text style from (1) to (2)? I couldn't find any solution in the internet.

**UPDATE**

I am not developing a program I just want to eliminate handy work and convert one text style to text with another style.

Comment: Do you mean pretty print? Or convert YAML to JSON (the first example without quotes around the keywords seems to be in the YAML format)?

Comment: I mean pretty print, not converting

Comment: Are you looking for a tool or code? If the latter - which programming language are you using?

Comment: I just have plain swagger text. And I want online or offline tool to change pretty print, I am not developing a program, I just want to change text style. Pretty print. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Paste your YAML into http://editor.swagger.io and then select the menu item **Edit > Convert to YAML**. This will pretty-print your YAML.